# How to read a "Drawbar Organ" tab?

Tags: tablature, organ

I found a tab format that I cannot decipher. And I know of different forms of piano tablatures, but I can't find this referenced anywhere.

How is one supposed to read this kind of "organ" tablature with numbers all over it and... I don't know what, exactly, in the tuning header?

[image: light my fire tab]

What is the correct name for this tablature style?
What are its advantages?

There's a site full of those, (it's called "songsterr") its operators look pretty certain of its unintelligibility, and this leaves me baffled.

Comment: It looks like standard guitar tab, except you couldn't physically play it on guitar (there's not way you could play frets 3 and 19 at the same time for example). It looks like it shows the "guitar" tuning is down a semitone from the standard tuning. But why anyone would want to play drawbar organ reading this notation, I can't possibly imagine!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's guitar tab, with semitone-down tuning.  It seems they've tried to notate the organ solo as guitar tab.  I suppose this could be useful to a guitarist, even if he couldn't play it literally.   Pianists often work from a 'piano-conductor' score that shows more information than can actually be played with two hands.  And of course there are full orchestral scores which are read but not played, not by one person at any rate!

Comment: it's actually obvious now that I look at it with fresh eyes. The time notation on the bottom drew me off track and sent me looking for some kind of alternative tab style.